# Drawing lines in UIView in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-graphics

This may be answered elsewhere, if so shame on me...

I am drawing a table in a UIView (which is added to a UITableViewcell), and I am currently laying out the text in rows and columns, but in terms of the borders, i'm using an image (a top line with corner radius, a bottom line, a vertical line and a horizontal line).

I want to draw these using the CGContextMoveToPoint code, but is it possible to specify the UIView to use? In the method everything is being added to a dynamically created view, I want to draw lines into that view before returning it.

It seems like this wouldn't work overriding the drawRect?

ie in pseudo code:

```
-(UIView *)myView {
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CG.....];
    foreach(NSDictionary *d in rowArray) {
        //draw left column text
        //draw right column text
    }
    //This is what i want to do?
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(myView?????);
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are drawing a table rather then just nesting another UITableView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to draw without an image in memory you have to do this with `drawRect` as it will be discarded every frame and not saved. if you want something saved you can create an image, paint to it, and add it to the view.

Comment: The key point is that in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch, you wait to be told to draw, and draw only then. You cannot simply draw to the screen whenever you want to. When something changes that's worth redrawing, set your view as needing display; the system will tell your view to draw at an appropriate time.

Comment: Your suggestion of creating an image and painting to it was extremely helpful, but also drawRect finally clicked in my head after reading your answer. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 2):

why not just creating a UIView subclass that will do the drawing stuff in drawRect: ?
I believe it's not a good idea for placing a drawing code outside drawRect: method.

Answer (score 0):

For stuff you just want to draw once, you can malloc a bitmap of the appropriate size, use that bitmap to create a CGBitmapContext, draw into that context, create an image from that context, and assign that CGImageRef to the CALayer of your UIView (or UIView overlay).

Comment: Or, subclass `CALayer` and implement `drawInContext:`. The layer will capture what you draw and store it in its `contents`.